# How can I plot Intensity values(Z) based on X and Y position. Data stored as 3 columns in CSV file

Tags: plotting, csv-format

I have a CSV data file with `X` position, `Y` position and corresponding intensity as `Z`.

I would like to plot it to form an image. I have an idea that list density plot is one method,but, somehow the importing of the CSV file as table and plotting is resulting in an error :

```
Read::readn: "Invalid real number found when reading from "test2 10 10.csv."
```

I am totally new to Mathematica and just learning. I don't understand why it takes so long to even import a CSV file.

Thanks !

Comment: It may help to get a good answer if you post your code and some example data. I'm sure you'll have a solution in no time at all then

Comment: Please try to isolate the specific issue that's causing problems, and post a minimal working examples (i.e. the *smallest* code snippet and input file that reproduces the problem).  It seems that you are having trouble importing from CSV---this is a separate problem from plotting.  We can't find out what goes wrong with the CSV import without seeing a sample data file (please try to create the smallest possible CSV that reproduces the problem, preferably just a few lines, and post it together with the code you used for importing)

Comment: Did you try `Import`?

Answer (score 7):

```
(*Testing ...
First we generate some points*)
points = Flatten[Table[{x, y, PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 2}, .5], {x, y}]}, 
                       {x, -3, 3, .1}, {y, -3, 3, .1}], 1];
(*
Now we export it as a csv
*)
Export["c:\\points.csv", points];

(* The file looks like this:
-3.,-3.,0.0010207851317789406
-3.,-2.9,0.0010190852401957891
-3.,-2.8,0.0010140025313558822
-3.,-2.7,0.0010055876210847213
-3.,-2.6,0.0009939239359647277
...
*)
(* Finally import it and plot*)

ListDensityPlot[Import["c:\\points.csv"]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

I had no problems at all downloading your sample file and plotting it:

[image]

Comment: example data in csv file : https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6yei5eTKtEsbEFVODUwblEzMjQ

Comment: @abhilashsukumari See edit

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the sample file, it seems that your data may be on a regular grid:

```
data = Import["wafer test 5-8-12 test5.csv"];

data = GatherBy[data, First];

Equal @@ dd[[All, All, 2]]

(*
==> True
*)
```

which means that we could also use `ArrayPlot`, if you want a more 'discrete' appearance:

```
ArrayPlot[Transpose[dd[[All, All, 3]]], ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"]
```

[image]

I had to transpose my data since I gathered by the `x` values, so each row of data ends up being constant `x` instead of `y`.  Also you might want to use the `DataReversed` option for `ArrayPlot`, since `ArrayPlot` and `ListDensityPlot` treat arrays slightly differently.